# Can you edit shape points in iOS version of Pages?

Tags: ios, pages

In the macOS version of Pages, I can select a shape and then use this command in the menus: *Format > Shapes and Lines > Make Editable*. Then I can manipulate the edges of the shape by moving adding points to the curves. For example, here is a square before and after.

[image]

Is there a way to do the same thing in the iOS version of pages?

I have an iPad Pro with pencil, so it would be easy to touch the small points.

Comment: You mean to, say resize a square, or do you mean to add a curve or another point?

Comment: I mean the latter. I've updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: That’s what I thought wanted to be sure. I haven’t found a way to do it yet. I usually do it on my Mac then open document in iOS later. I’ll keep an eye on this one.